# Existence of limit when encountering $\frac00$

Tags: limits

I have this limit, which ends up as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{x}$ which yields $\frac00$.

Normally, one would say that this limit doesn't exist, but at the same time, we have L'Hopital's rule which often times can deal with this.

**My question is:** How do I know for certain that the limit doesn't exist? And I'm talking in general here, not just for the above-mentioned example. I mean, some times, you can do L'Hopital 3 times, still giving 0/0, but on the 4th time, you get a defined value. Where does one draw the line and say "no, it doesn't exist"?

Comment: I'm not sure how general it's possible to get, but in this case you can look at the limit as $x$ tends to zero through positive and negative values separately.  You will find that you get two different answers.  That is, the function approaches different values if $x$ approaches $0$ from the right or the left, so if we just want to say "$x$ approaches zero" without specifying right or left, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: Before applying any machinery, it is useful to look at the function. It would be nice if the denominator did not *approach* $0$. But unfortunately it does. So let us look at the behaviour of the function *near* $0$. The answer is clear, the function is identically $1$ for $x$ positive, and identically $-1$ for $x$ negative.

Comment: Sorry but how does L'Hopital's rule enter the picture here?

Comment: About the (separate) question of when to go on with L'Hospital's Rule: when there are clear signs of progress.

Comment: You are incorrect to say "normally, a limit of the form $0/0$ doesn't exist". The *form* $0/0$ is an indeterminate one, meaning that it doesn't tell you what the limit is. In fact, it's as bad as an indeterminate form can possibly be, since it gives you no information whatsoever about what the limit can be or if it exists. (The *algebraic expression* $0/0$ is undefined, but that only has an indirect relation to any of the above: specifically, the fact the *form* $0/0$ is indeterminate is a compelling reason why we should not define a value for the *algebraic expression* $0/0$)

Comment: @Hurkyl - Good point! I guess what I meant to say was that when one encounters the 0/0 phenomenon, one tends to conclude that the limit leading to it doesn't exist. I guess that would be a wrong assumption. Then it's sad to say that so many learning resources, particularly online, tend to draw this conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for real $x, |x|=+\sqrt{x^2}$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{ |x|}x=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{-x}x=-1$$ as $x\to0\implies x\ne0$

Similarly, $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{ |x|}x=+1$$

So, the left & the right are not same